# Asteroid identification in fits image

Tags: observational-astronomy, asteroids

I have a fits image, and I need to identify an asteroid. What characteristics  do I look out for?

Comment: "Location, location, location."  If the FITS metadata includes coordinates, you've found the asteroid.  Otherwise it's hard to see how you could identify any but the most unusual asteroids.

Comment: A time is also needed, asteroids move after all...